# How to save python pptx on colab

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, python-pptx

Is there a way to save the Python pptx file on Google drive or desktop?

I tried `Prs.save()` to save the pptx file, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that illustrates the problem you observe.

Answer (score 0):

Your presentation will be saving to the Files panel on the left of Colab:
[image: Colab Files Panel]

From here you can download the saved presentation file.

If you want to save to Google Drive you need to mount the drive (icon is at the top of the Files panel) and then simply append the relevant path to your file name when saving:

```
prs.save("/content/drive/My Drive/.../presentation.pptx")
```